# how to fix "The application is improperly formatted" error?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm publishing an application that works fine on my computer (windows 10) but doesn't work on the target machine (windows 7)

i tried publishing without signing the ClickOnce manifest, I've set all the references copy local to true, I made sure that the target machine .NET version is the same, I have gone through all the similar topics on stack overflow and nothing has helped me.

> Cannot continue. The application is improperly formatted. Contact the application vendor for assistance.

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
                Windows                                             : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
                Common Language Runtime       : 4.0.30319.42000
                System.Deployment.dll                                : 4.7.3221.0 built by: NET472REL1LAST_C
                clr.dll                                     : 4.7.3394.0 built by: NET472REL1LAST_C
                dfdll.dll                                                 : 4.7.3221.0 built by: NET472REL1LAST_C
                dfshim.dll                                            : 4.0.41209.0 (Main.041209-0000)
```

> SOURCES
>                   Deployment url                                                : file:///I:/Systems/Systems%20Team/Piotr/USELESS/MBID.application
>
> ERROR SUMMARY
>                   Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
>                   * Activation of I:\Systems\Systems Team\Piotr\USELESS\MBID.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
>                                   + Exception reading manifest from file:///I:/Systems/Systems%20Team/Piotr/USELESS/MBID.application: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
>                                   + Deployment manifest is not semantically valid.
>                                   + Deployment manifest identity contains missing or unsupported processor architecture.
>
> COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
>                   No transaction error was detected.
>
> WARNINGS
>                   There were no warnings during this operation.
>
> OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
>                   * [05/06/2019 12:34:14] : Activation of I:\Systems\Systems Team\Piotr\USELESS\MBID.application has started.
>
> ERROR DETAILS
>                   Following errors were detected during this operation.
>                   * [05/06/2019 12:34:14] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestParse)
>                                   - Exception reading manifest from file:///I:/Systems/Systems%20Team/Piotr/USELESS/MBID.application: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
>                                   - Source: System.Deployment
>                                   - Stack trace:
>                                                   at  System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)
>                                                   at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestDirectBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
>                                                   at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
>                                                   at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl, Uri& deploymentUri)
>                                                   at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>                                                   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>                                                   at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
>                                                   at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
>                                   --- Inner Exception ---
>                                   System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestSemanticValidation)
>                                   - Deployment manifest is not semantically valid.
>                                   - Source: System.Deployment
>                                   - Stack trace:
>                                                   at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.ValidateSemanticsForDeploymentRole()
>                                                   at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)
>                                   --- Inner Exception ---
>                                   System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (InvalidManifest)
>                                   - Deployment manifest identity contains missing or unsupported processor architecture.
>                                   - Source: System.Deployment
>                                   - Stack trace:
>                                                   at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.ValidateSemanticsForDeploymentRole()
>
> COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
>                   No transaction information is available.

I need to get this thing working.

Comment: This looks like a clue: _"Deployment manifest identity contains missing or unsupported processor architecture."_

Comment: Did you try to deploy a 64-bit application to a 32-bit machine?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it's set to 'Any CPU' so should work on both apparently. I deployed many similar applications in this job and never had this problem before.

Comment: @piotrb92 the error comes from the installation package, not the executable. The error complains about a `missing or unsupported processor architecture`. Did you try to deploy to a 32-bit machine? It could be that the *package* targets x64 only

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for the support, I will try that now and confirm if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After publishing a version specifically for 32-bit machine, it worked with no errors as advised by Panagiotis Kanavos.